# Inequality with real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Given $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$, it is possible to obtain an inequality of the type:
\begin{equation}
a^2 - b^2 \leqslant C(a - b)^2,
\end{equation}
for some $C > 0$ ?
I was able to show through Young's inequality that it's hold that $a^2 - b^2 \leqslant 2(a + b)^2$.
But I cannot see whether the first inequality is true in general.

Comment: Just set $a = b+1$ to see that this is not possible.

Comment: What happens to the left hand side when $a=b+1$ and $b\to \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=b$ the inequality is always true, so let assume $a\neq b$

The inequality is reduced to $a+b\le C(a-b)\iff C\ge \dfrac{a+b}{a-b}$

But the RHS can take arbitrary large values, e.g. $a=1+\frac 1n$ and $b=1$, then

$C\ge \dfrac{2+\frac 1n}{\frac 1n}=2n+1\to\infty$

So if $C$ is fixed, the inequality cannot stand for all reals $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such inequality. For $a = b+1$ you would have
$$
 2b+1 = (b+1)^2 - b^2 \le C
$$
with a fixed $C> 0$ and arbitrary $b \in \Bbb R$, which is not possible.

Comment: Does this show that there is no $C > 0$ that makes the inequality true?

Comment: @José: Yes, that is what I tried to say.

Comment: @José What do you think?